# Nano-X (Microwindow) Programming guide?

Tags: windows, linux, embedded, embedded-linux

I want to know some basic programming guide for Nano-X (Microwindow, Embedded GUI). I know it's windows based programming but i want some of the tutorials where i can learn it something better.
I also want to display icon or images on LCD, so how it is possible in Nano-X or Microwindow ?

I also want User API manual for Microwindow API (not Nano-X) ? can some one help me ?

Thanks,
neel

Answer (score 2):

I know this comes an year too late but maybe this can be useful for someone.

http://embedded.centurysoftware.com/docs/nx/